# Please explain why this is true.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> If $T=n^2-n-12$ is a positive number, explain why $T$ is composite for all values of $n > 5$.

**Attempt:**

I factorised to get $4$ and $-3$.

But I cannot prove how all numbers are composite.

Could you show me how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, as you say $T(n)=(n-4)(n+3)$.  And $n>5 \implies n-4>1$ so....

Comment: The claim is only generally true for integers $n>5$

Comment: Please edit to choose a title that actually explains what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

You already did the work!
$$
T=(n-4)(n+3)
$$
A product of two positive numbers, neither equal to 1, as long as $n>5$, showing that it is composite.

Answer (score 0):

$n^2-n-12=(n-4)(n+3)$. For $n>5$, we have $n-4>1,n+2>1$. Thus $n^2-n-12$ is a composite.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$T(n)=n^2-n-12=(n-4)(n+3)$$

If $n>5$ is an integer , $T(n)$ is the product of two integers greater than $1$, hence composite.

Answer (score 0):

Just to present a different argument:  If $n$ is even, then your expression is clearly even.  But if $n$ is odd then $n^2-n$ is the difference of two odd numbers, hence even, so your expression is even again.

You need to argue that it can't be $2$, but that's not too hard (the min occurs when $n=\frac 12$ and the function is strictly increasing from there with $T(5)=8$).

Answer (score 0):

$$(n-4)(n+3)$$
for $n>5$

$n\rightarrow m+4\quad m=2,3....$
$$(m)(m+7)$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am waiting to know why??

Comment: I didn't downvote but your answer comprises two expressions and some pseudo-matthematical guff about ranges and no actual mathematical statements.

Answer (score 0):

$T=n^2-n-12=n(n-1)-12$. But $n(n-1)$ and $12$ are both even so their difference is also even. For $n=4$ we get $T=0$. For any other value of $n>4$, $T$ is an even greater than $2$ so it is composite.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove when $n > 5$ then  $n^2 - n - 12 = ab$ for some $a$ and some $b$; $a,b > 1; a,b \in \mathbb N$.

Okay, let $a = n -4$ and $b = n+ 3$.  Then $n^2 - n = 12 = (n-4)(n+3) = ab$.

That's it.  We're done.